# react-native-gradle-plugin and gradlew assembleDebug not working

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin

when i try to use `gradlew assembleDebug` to build my apk with Java 17 and gradle 7.3 i have this problem:

```
e: C:\Users\Osama\Desktop\expo-app\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\tasks\BundleHermesCTask.kt: (138, 11): This declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked with '@kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi' or '@OptIn(kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s

1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

This is my gradle wrapper  properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

distributionPath=wrapper/dists

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-bin.zip

zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Hello Guys. when i try to use `gradlew assembleDebug` to build my apk with Java 17 and gradle 7.3 i have this problem:

```
e: C:\Users\Osama\Desktop\expo-app\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\tasks\BundleHermesCTask.kt: (138, 11): This declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked with @kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi' or '@OptIn(kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s

1 actionable task: 1 executed

This is my gradle wrapper  properties:

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

distributionPath=wrapper/dists

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-bin.zip

zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

I tried `gradlew assembleDebug` many times and I expected to build my apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue a few weeks ago and I had to upgrade react-native version to fix this issue. I upgraded react native 0.65 to 0.69

If you need help with upgrading your React native project check the official documentation on [Upgrading to new versions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading)