# when running a npm start (react native) i get an error (react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED)

Tags: java, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

PS C:\Users\akram\Desktop\mobileApp> npx react-native run-android
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED
> 1 actionable task: 1 executed
> e: C:\Users\akram\Desktop\mobileApp\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\tasks\BundleHermesCTask.kt: (138, 11): This declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked with '@kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi' or '@OptIn(kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
e: C:\Users\akram\Desktop\mobileApp\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\tasks\BundleHermesCTask.kt: (138, 11): This declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked with '@kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi' or '@OptIn(kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\akram\Desktop\mobileApp\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\akram\Desktop\mobileApp\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\akram\Desktop\mobileApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\akram\Desktop\mobileApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

i tried removing node-modules and reinstalling but same error appears

Comment: seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593725/react-native-gradle-plugin-and-gradlew-assembledebug-not-working/76602753#76602753 hope this help